# If $\det\left(\begin{smallmatrix}a & 1 & 1\\1 & b & 1\\1 & 1 & c\end{smallmatrix}\right) > 0 $ then prove that $abc> -8$

Tags: matrices, inequality, determinant

> If the value of the determinant $$\begin{vmatrix}
> a & 1 & 1\\
> 1 & b & 1\\
> 1 & 1 & c
> \end{vmatrix} > 0 $$ then prove that $abc> -8$

---

I have calculated its determinant and got

$$abc - (a+b+c) > -2$$

Please tell me how to proceed further to the given answer form.

Comment: May be $a,b,c>0$. Then $\displaystyle a+b+c\geq (abc)^{\frac{1}{3}}.$

Comment: @DXT That's probably not the case, as we _want to prove_ that $abc>-8$.

Comment: Please determine the domain of variables. Are $a$, $b$ and $c$ integer numbers? Thanks

Comment: Even with a restriction to integer values, $(a,b,c) = (-1,-1,-10000)$ has $abc$ pretty far below $-8$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Based on your comment, the values $(-1,-1,-({10}^k))$ for any positive integer number $k$ is a counterexample. Am I right?

Comment: Right (or even $(-1,-1,-k)$ for any positive integer $k$). The determinant is always $4$ for any such value of $k$.

Comment: @user0410 yes $a,b,c$ are integers

Comment: @user168282 Your claim is incorrect. Please see the last comment of MishaLavrov as a nice counterexample.

Comment: @user0410 yes she is right. There must be some error in the question

Comment: @MishaLavrov I suggest to post your comment as an answer. Its a nice answer. I like it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another counterexample to this claim is $(a,b,c) = (-1,-1,-k)$ for any $k\ge 8$. Then 
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a & 1 & 1\\
1 & b & 1\\
1 & 1 & c
\end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
-1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & -1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & -k
\end{vmatrix} = 4
$$
for any choice of $k$, but $abc = -k$ can be made as small as we want.

Answer (score 3):

When $a=b=-3$ and $c=-0.9$, $abc-(a+b+c)=-1.2>-2$ but $abc=-8.1<-8$.